# implement photoshot-like overlay on android

Tags: android, image

I have 2 images and I want to overlay them and get the same effect as in photoshop's "overlay". Overlay porterduff exist in PorterDuff'd documentation but I guess not for android 2.2.

any idea on how to implement this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

They have added it to the PorterDuff.Mode enum, but im not sure from what api version, im pretty sure it's >2.2.[api doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html)

You can just use LIGHTEN and darken your dst image to achieve a similar effect :)